# TP-LINK TL-WR841N обрывается соединение

Tags: wifi, роутер, tp-link

TP-LINK TL-WR841N обрывает соединение после соединения ноутбука к Wi-Fi. Проблема возникает при подключении конкретного устройства.

После подключения ноута к сети проходит некоторое время (минут 5-10) и начинается:

- Появляется иконка "Без доступа к Интернету" в трее для сети
- Все устройства автоматически отключаются от сети
- В списке сетей появляется эта сеть, но подключиться к ней уже не получается, помогает только перезагрузка.

После перезагрузки все повторяется

Comment: Троянов нет? Может он какой-то мусорный трафик создаёт? И провайдер за это блокирует вообще всё.

Comment: у меня было такое, вылечил заменой роутера

Comment: @qwertiy тоже об этом думал. Почти два дня сижу, мониторю трафик. Собственно, кроме Хрома и Оперы ничего такого и не видно, что могло бы сильно нагружать. https://yadi.sk/i/zQBUWMvhE9RM3Q

Comment: @maximlensky роутер был этой же модели? (TL-WR841N)

Comment: нее , у меня была Tenda и жила эта Tenda 8 лет

Comment: Версия какая прошивки и аппаратной части? на тплинках и не такие глюки вылезают. даже есть аппаратные болезни у atheros чипов. может неправильная калибровка радиочасти на заводе тплинк, может плохая схема питания.

я бы сменил роутер.